# PHP function to get days between start and end dates

Tags: php, date

I have the following PHP function that should return the days between two dates.
For some reasons one day is always duplicated.

```
$plusOneWeek = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 week"));
$dates = getDates(date("Y-m-d"), $plusOneWeek);

function getDates($startTime, $endTime) {
    $day = 86400;
    $format = 'Y-m-d';
    $startTime = strtotime($startTime);
    $endTime = strtotime($endTime);
    //$numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day) + 1;
    $numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day); // remove increment

    $days = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numDays; $i++) { //change $i to 1
        $addDay = date($format, ($startTime + ($i * $day)));
        $days[] = $addDay;
    }

    return $days;
}
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-10-23
    [1] => 2015-10-24
    [2] => 2015-10-25
    [3] => 2015-10-25
    [4] => 2015-10-26
    [5] => 2015-10-27
    [6] => 2015-10-28
)
```

As you see this date `2015-10-25` is there two times. I cannot understand why.

Comment: and why don't you use DateTime:diff() ?

Comment: I just ran this code- I did not have the same result.  Are you sure?!

Comment: I ran this code as well and results are good. There are no duplicates

Comment: I get the expected result. No duplication!

Comment: Guys I don t get the exact result. It is duplicated for me...how is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

If i ran your code i don't get duplicates, but anyway i would avoid the `round()` method completely (it is also shorter).

```
function getDates($startTime, $endTime){
    $days = array();
    $currentDay = $startTime;
    do {
      $days[] = $currentDay;
      $currentDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDay .' +1 day'));          
    } while ($currentDay < $endTime);
    return $days;
}
```

(Feel free to add some error handling, for example if `$endTime < $startTime` and so on)

Comment: Hi this works better, but it is starting from tomorrow instead than today. How?

Comment: I just read, that you want to return the days between two dates - wasn't sure if this includes the day. I updated the code.